# WCF and ASMX in same project

Tags: web-services, wcf, asmx

I'm currently in the 'need' to add a WCF service in a project where I have 5 .asmx services.

Is it bad or may I enter into some nasty problems doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without any problem. But for better maintainability & extensibility I suggest to use **"Service Gateway Pattern".**

[image]

In Service Gateway Pattern, you have to create a separate project that decouples service logic from your end has minimal effect of change in service to the end point. It is also useful when you are consuming services of different kind and/or from different sources.

**Advantages:**

- Decoupling the service access logic from the rest of the application
  makes it easy to change the service the application accesses. For
  example, you may want to switch to a new version of the same service,
  or you may want to use a service with better service-level guarantees
  from another vendor. Switching to another service is much easier if
  you can automatically generate the code that does the data mapping.
- Service Gateway hides the complexities of accessing a service from
  the application. This improves reuse of both the application
  components and the service access components. The application has no
  direct reference to the service, so it is independent of any
  implementation details and the location of the service. Encapsulating
  the service access logic in a separate layer also improves the reuse
  of the access logic because it can now be used across multiple
  service calls as long as the same transport and authentication
  mechanism is used.
- Service Gateway provides an ideal location for providing common
  features such as asynchronous invocation, caching, and error
  handling.
- If you are using services form multiple 3rd parties, if hides all differences & stream line usage on client.

Please refer msdn [**Service Gateway**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650101.aspx) link for more details.